# What do these verses mean?

Tags: meaning

Quotation from [The Pastyme of Plasure](http://archive.org/details/pastimepleasure00wriggoog)
Especially，I don't know "sprynge, ryall, chefe and orygynal".

> "O Mayster Lydgate! the most dulcet sprynge
>     Of famous rethoryke, with balade ryall
>     The chefe orygynal."
>     *—"The Pastyme of Plasure," by Stephen Hawes, 1509.*

[image: Scan of verse]

Comment: Middle English is one of my favorite things to read aloud. Try saying the words phonetically (at a decent pace), and you'll find it often sounds close to Modern English with a peculiar accent. It makes determining the meaning fairly easy in some cases.

Comment: I am vastly curious to know what course of reading is leading to your very interesting but quite eccentric series of questions!

Answer (score 7):

"O Master Lydgate! the sweetest source of famous rhetoric, and of ballad royal the chief originator."

*Rhyme royal* was a standard form of English narrative verse from Chaucer down to the fifteenth century: seven lines, usually of five but occasionally of four iambic feet, rhyming a-b-a-b-b-cc.

*Ballad royal* was an English variant of the French 'fixed form' ballade: four stanzas of rhyme royal, with all four stanzas using the same rhymes and ending in the same refrain.

However, nomenclature was flexible in the days of Lydgate and his successors; Hawes is probably speaking of Lydgate's huge output of rhyme royal rather than of works in the short form. The stage directions to Lydgate's *Bycorne and Chychevache* employ the term *balade* for what we would call *stanza*, e.g. *First there shal stonde an ymage in poete-wyse seying thees thre balades*, which is followed by three stanzas of rhyme royal.

Answer (score 5):

Sprynge = spring (as in source of a river)

Ryall = real

Chefe = chief

Orygynal = orginal

So, a little freely, 'O Master Lydgate! the sweetest spring of famous rhetoric, the main original writer of real song.'

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Middle English.

Comment: -1 deserved for getting _ryall_ wrong.

Comment: Actually, Barrie, you didn't get *ryall* wrong; you're just a little dated. :) See OED "† **real**, *a.¹* (and *sb.²* ) *Obs.*"  Its adjectival sense is "Royal, regal, kingly."  We just don't use *real* in that way any longer in English. Note that Spanish preserves both senses yet, where *real* means both *royal* and the contemporary English sense of "Royal, regal, kingly."